# Define MPC manipulated variables as pulses

Tags: matlab, simulink, mpc

I have a model of a simple power system in simulink where I want to control the voltage stability. The only thing I can control is the tap position of my OLTC(On Load Tap Changer). Therefore, I have two inputs to my plant; "up" and "down" which goes into the OLTC. If "up" is a single pulse then the OLTC change tap position from 0 to 1, and if "down" is a single pulse then OLTC change tap from 0 to -1. So, the OLTC allows only pulses, when the signal is changing from 0 to 1. The OLTC has a maximum and minimum tap position of [8 -8]. This means that there is 17 different tap postions, including tap 0, of the OLTC.

My problem is that I dont know how to define that my MPC manipulated variables(MPC.mv) needs to take the form of a pulse in order to control the OLTC. What I want is to force the MPC.mv signal to be discrete, to generate 3 pulses I want the MPC.mv to look something like [0 1 0 1 0 1 0].

This is my first time posting here, if there is some essential information I have missed to provide pls let me know.